# how to associate a randomly generated key with mysql primary key using php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table in which I storing files uploaded by users and a php page which is showing all the files uploaded by a particular user. There is a download link when user clicks on that link I am passing the file id to my `download.php` page then in download.php page I am retrieving file data using that id. I want to generate a random key each time a user click a download link for a particular file and using this key and file id I want to retrieve file data from database.
How can I do it.

Comment: It's not very clear to me, why would you need a random key if you already have the file ID that allows you to get the file from DB?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a second table where you store your random keys and link them to the files you want to have downloaded.

Example:

```
|-------|-------------------------|
| key   | file                    |
|-------|-------------------------|
| jfdhj | /downloads/somefile.txt |
|-------|-------------------------|
```

Of course, you could use the ID of the file in the `file` column, and join it. The reason to do this, is that you can create several keys for one file.

Also: why not just use the ID from the database?

Comment: I want the key to be randomly generated every time the user logs in or clicks on download link.